# How do I access/use the name of an R object in a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I will need to create a number of reference tables where I specify the number of academic credits a student is supposed to have to achieved, given a certain programme and time period.

I have a list of start dates and programmes for each individual student in the data frame "fulldata". 
As a first step, I want to use this data frame to get a list of unique start dates for a certain programme. Ideally, I would be able to automate this (and later) step(s) via a function since there are a lot of programmes.

At present I have three programmes, Economics(Ekonomi), Real Estate and Digital Media. I have three corresponding R-objects (containing a vector of academic credits for each module in order) named "Ekonomi", "Real Estate" and "Digital media". I want to fetch the unique values of start_date from "fulldata" where the program name equals the name of my current R object

I write:

```
start_dates<-function(x){
sd<-fulldata%>%filter(program==deparse(substitute(x)))%>%
dplyr::select(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)%>%drop_na()%>%unique()
}
```

So for `start_dates(Ekonomi)` the function should fetch the start dates for observations with programme equal to "Ekonomi". This does not seem to work however.

When i write

```
start_dates(Ekonomi)
sd
```

It turns out that sd does not contain any observations.

I can write:

```
sd<-fulldata%>%filter(program==deparse(substitute(Ekonomi)))%>%
dplyr::select(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)%>%drop_na()%>%unique()
}
```

....and then sd turns out completely fine, but I don't seem to be able to do the same thing with a function.

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

```
Small exerpt of data:

structure(list(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM = structure(c(15586, 
15586, 15586, 15586, 15586, 15586, 15586, 15586, NA, 15586, 15586, 
NA, 15586, 15586, 15586, NA, 15586, 15586, 15586, 15586), class = "Date"), 
    program = c("Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", "Ekonom", 
    "Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", 
    "Mäklarekonom", "Ekonom", "Ekonom", "Mäklarekonom", "Mäklarekonom"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: That produces 1 variables and 0 observations which is incorrect.

Comment: Check out https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/

Comment: @RonakShah

No, there's a typo in my question but the result is the same when I type sd<-summer_breaks(Ekonom)
sd

Comment: @alanocallaghan

Would you care to elaborate? Which part of the book should I consult?

Comment: It's not a book, it's a technical document describing how to do what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an unquoted variable to filter, one way is to use `rlang::enexpr(x)`

```
library(dplyr)

start_dates<-function(fulldata, x){

  fulldata%>%
    filter(program == as.character(rlang::enexpr(x))) %>%
    distinct(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)
}

start_dates(full_data, Ekonom)

# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM
#  <date>                         
#1 2012-09-03
```

Passing a quoted variable would not require any of these and can be directly done as

```
start_dates<-function(fulldata, x){
   fulldata%>%
     filter(program == x) %>%
     distinct(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)
}

start_dates(full_data, "Ekonom")
```

Comment: If I write 


start_dates<-function(fulldata, x){
    fulldata%>%
    filter(program == x) %>%
    distinct(UTBILDNINGSTILLFALLE_STARTDATUM)
 }
> sd<-start_dates(fulldata,Ekonom)

I get an error message saying that "In program == x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"?

Comment: nvm, I guess that's what you meant by quoted and unquoted variables

Comment: Okay, accepting this as correct answer (this somehow reminds me of macros in SAS), thank you for your time!

Comment: @Magnus yes, this is unquoted argument `start_dates(full_data, Ekonom)` and this is quoted `start_dates(full_data, "Ekonom")`.

Comment: Unsure if I should post a new question but...the solution with rlang::enexpr works fine on its own, but if I try to use it to create a variable within the function I get an error message saying that "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length."

Comment: In NSE, you have to use different functions based on what you want to do. Here we use `as.character(enexpr(x)) `  to convert an unquoted variable to string. If you want to create a new column with the passed value of `x` it requires mostly `!!sym(x) := ` but depending on the context it might vary. Better to ask a new question adding the necessary details.

Comment: Right: posting new question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718745/how-do-i-access-use-the-name-of-an-r-object-in-a-function-part-2